# How do I distinguish a Private college from a government one in India?

Tags: graduate-admissions

Government universities in India endorse government and private degree colleges. How do I distinguish between them? By distinction I mean any particular information that will help me determine (from the website) if a college is a private one.

Comment: Do you want to distinguish between private colleges and government colleges or Private universities and Government Universities?
Colleges in India usually have funding from mixed sources both private and government. In case of degree granting universities, the distinction can be easier.

Comment: I wish to distinguish between private colleges and government colleges affiliated to Government Universities.@KnIn

Comment: If the college does not indicate if it is a private college on its web site, no one can tell except themselves.  Think this way, you indicate your location is in India in your user profile, so I know you are likely from India. Suppose you did not indicate your location in the profile, then we don't know where you're from except those who know your IP(such as sys admin and mods).

Comment: Vote to close as the answer depends on individual factors.

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of searching online turns up many lists that others have compiled that can help you distinguish whether the nature of a university in India, including whether or not it is private.

A good starting point may be Wikipedia's ["List of private universities in India"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_private_universities_in_India)

Comment: I'm not into private universities. Please read the question/ the comments.